# Links or button roles within a nav tag

Tags: html, hyperlink, roles, menuitem, nav

Is it always necessary to use `role="link"`within the `a` tag or no more because I use HTML5 mark up?

```
<nav>
    <a href="home.html" role="link">HOME</a>
    <a href="about.html" role="link">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="contact.html" role="link">CONTACT</a>
</nav>
```

As you see they are just simple links, MENU ITEMS, no dropdowns, no complexity. so, should I **remove** the role attribute?

Comment: No. It is pointless for `a` elements, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_link_role

Answer (score 0):

From MDN

> Note: Where possible, it is recommended that you use a native 
> element rather than the link role, as native elements are more widely
> supported by older user agents and assistive technology. Native 
> elements also support keyboard and focus requirements by default,
> without need for additional customization.

I think it's unnecessary in this case, since your items are already links.